# Variable in React is undefined on first render but defined after re-rendering. (Uncaught TypeError: vairable is undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, axios

When I try to show the title of a movie (line 8 of App.js) I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: movies[0] is undefined". If I do a log of the variable "movies" after line 5 the console makes two logs: Frist, logs movies as an empty array and then logs movies as an array with all the content, like I want.

The weird thing is that if I delete the line 8 `{movies[0].title}` and save the error dissapears as normal, but then if I add it again and save the movie title renders on screen like I'm trying to do.

App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import useApi from './useApi';

function App() {
  const movies = useApi();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {movies[0].title}
    </div>
  );    
}

export default App;
```

My useApi returns an array with a list of movies:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useApi = () => {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

    const getData = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await axios(url);
            setMovies(res.data.results);
        } catch (error) {
            return [];
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, [])

    return movies;
}

export default useApi;
```

Knowing that if I print movies it logs an empty array but then it prints it normal like I said, i guess I'm having a problem with asynchrony but I can't figure out what. And the fact that it works when removing and readding line 8 makes me more confused.

Comment: You'll want to do `{movies[0] ? movies[0].title : "Loading..."}` or something like that in your JSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `getData()` function render two times in `useEffects` hook. You need to check `if(movies.length>0)` and after that type return!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the notion of conditional rendering. Something like this may work:

```
import './App.css';
import useApi from './useApi';

function App() {
  const movies = useApi();
  
  if (movies.length) { // conditionally render when the movie list is not empty
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {movies[0].title}
      </div>
    );
  }
  return <div>Loading...</div>   
}

export default App;
```